# Graph data structure - How are they represented in real world apps?

Tags: algorithm, graph

My text uses vertices as integers used to represent an index of an array. I'm not sure if this is to simplify the concept, or if it's actually used in practice.

How are they represented in the real world? Integers of array indices? Objects of map keys?

Maybe someone could also add some real world graph applications/libraries that give light to how they're represented?

Answer (score 1):

Use the minimum needed. If integers satisfy your need, then use them.
If extra data per node is required, use some objects.
Also you can use both integers and objects for a node, and make sure the integers are contiguous starting from 0.

That is for the nodes (vertices).

For edges, you have few data structures, adjacency list, adjacency matrix, list of edges, incidence matrix and maybe few other. Read more about them in a book on algorithms or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to represent graphs as list of edges (vertex 1,vertex 2) in a form of Python list it would be

```
graph = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],....,[1,5]]
```

or similar (numbers here are just for example. In a real life you probably want to use graph databases (type of NoSQL storage for graphs) like Neo4J (implemented using java,see http://neo4j.com/ ) or cayley (implemented using go) https://github.com/google/cayley

Answer (score 0):

How two people/things/nodes are connected. what's the relation between them. facebook is the great example of it.

consider these problem

1) `Number of mutual friends you have with your friend "Harry"`.

2) `using google maps, tell me the shortest path to reach from place A to place B`

All of these problems are graph based.
I would suggest you to solve graph problems with adjacency list and matrix too, You will get to know when to use which representation.